# How do I allow users to access folder & file selection dialog with <input /> tag?

Tags: reactjs

It's possible in HTML with

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
```

But React doesn't seem to understand `webkitdirectory` and `directory` props passed to the input.

How do I enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it works you need to pass an empty strings for `directory` and `webkitdirectory` attributes (source: [https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3468](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3468#issuecomment-448336672)).

Here is React's blog post introducing the rendering of unknown DOM attributes: [DOM Attributes in React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html)

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" directory="" webkitdirectory="" />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add empty string It will work

```
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

------------Or-------------

You can do this in componentDidMount() method by putting a ref on the node.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.x.directory = true;
        this.refs.x.webkitdirectory = true;
    }
```